# Lattice Homomorphisms and Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated, module-isomorphism

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated modules over some (possibly non-commutative) ring $R$. Let there be a lattice isomorphism between the lattice of submodules of $M$ and those of $N$ (i.e. their respective sets of submodules can be put into bijection with one another). Is this sufficient for there to be a $\textit{module}$ homomorphism between $M$ and $N$? If so, what conditions do $M$ and $N$ need to fulfill in order for this to be an injection, or a surjection?

Comment: There is always a homomorphism between any two modules (the zero homomorphism).

Comment: And it’s not possible to do better than the zero homomorphism in general: consider $R = S \times S$ and let $M, N$ be the same module but over the left resp. right copy of $S$. Also, a lattice isomorphism requires more than just a bijection.